# How to delete information from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command creator where users do !create  
Currently this part works perfectly. Now I need a way to delete it, and I can't figure out how to.

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  name: 'delete',
  execute(message, args) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      return message.reply('Please add more params! !delete <commandName>');
    }
    var data = fs.readFileSync('commands.json', 'utf8');
    var cmds = JSON.parse(data);
    var cmd = cmds.commands;
    try {
      var i, jsonCmd, jsonMsg;
      for (i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++) {
        jsonCmd = cmd[i].name;
        if (args[0] === jsonCmd) {
          delete cmd[i];
          return message.channel.send(message.author + " Command " + jsonCmd + " deleted!");
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

JSON file

```
{
  "commands":
    [
      { "name": "test2", "message": "test2" },
      { "name": "test3", "message": "test3" },
      { "name": "test4", "message": "test4" },
      { "name": "test5", "message": "test5" },
      { "name": "true", "message": "\\<:LULW:572545743798140940>" },
      { "name": "space", "message": "this message has spaces" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `delete cmd[i]` should (and does) delete the array entry, leaving an *empty slot* - but since you immediately return from the execute function once you found the "command", it prompts me to ask ... why are you deleting anything anyway

Comment: I figured that's what it does, I was testing to see if it even works.

Comment: `it added null to the array`, use `splice` then!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it from the JSON file you have to add a 
`fs.writeFileSync("commands.json", JSON.stringify(cmds));` after the delete.

Comment: When I did this it added null to the array, which broke it.